# NyroModal Not Working On Added Links with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, nyromodal, jquery-click-event

I have this NyroModal:

```
$('.openModal').nyroModal();
```

And then I have my Link:

```
<a href="#sample" class="openModal">this is a test</a>
```

This works great, it loads my sample modal like it's supposed to, but when I add a link using

```
$("#mydiv").html('<a href="#sample" class="openModal">this is a test</a>');
```

It doesn't work, I have tried this

```
$('.openModal a').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).nyroModalManual();
        return false;
});
```

And this:

```
$('.openModal a').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).nmManual("#sample");
        return false;
    });
```

But I haven't had any luck, can you think of anything else I could try? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE: I forgot to mention I get no errors at all in my console

UPDATE 2: I am now getting this error, now that I'm selecting it properly:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'nyroModalManual'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about his ?

```
$('.openModal a').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.nmManual("#sample");
    });
```

or I guess this selector do you have :

```
$('a.openModal').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.nmManual("#sample");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like you want a.openModal as your selector.  Currently its selecting a elements inside something with class openModal.
  You might want to look into delegate instead, iirc thats preferred now.

I see your update. Aren't you supposed to call it with nyroModal, not nyroModalManual?  nmManual looks like it might be valid too.

Comment: Hi corn_dog, thank you for your response, I have tried it, and it does indeed appear that I wasn't selecting the element properly. However, I'm now getting an error, I updated my question with what it's saying. Thanks again